# Prolog: getting rid of a recursive helper predicate

Tags: prolog, predicate, logic-programming

So I'm trying to get rid of the wrapper clause by using the sort library predicate directly inside split. What split does is just generating a list of numbers from a list that looks like this: [1:2,3:2,4:6] ---split--> [1,2,3,2,4,6]. But the generated list contains duplicates, and I don't want that, so I'm using the wrapper to combine split and sort, which then generates the desired result: [1,2,3,4,6].

I'd really like to get rid of the wrapper and just use sort within split, however I keep getting "ERROR: sort/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated." Any ideas? Thanks :)

```
split([],[]).
split([H1:H2|T],[H1,H2|NT]) :-
    split(T,NT).

wrapper(L,Processed) :- 
    split(L,L2),
    sort(L2,Processed).
```

Comment: The term `[1:2,3:2,4:6]` looks odd to me, what is it for? and what is this `ins(T,NT)`?

Comment: ins should be split called recursively, my bad :). fixed. [1:2..] is a list of edges in a graph.

Comment: You will never get that error message with your definition of `split/2`. That's impossible!

Comment: I will get it if I use it somewhere within the body of split.

Comment: If you call `wrapper/2` you will **never** get that error message, because upon success of `split(L,L2)` the variable `L2` will be a wellformed list. Your program seems to be OK now.

Comment: yes. My program works beautifully. However, as I said, I really don't care for the wrapper, and want to restructure my code so that there is no need for it.

Comment: Not clear, what you mean by wrapper. You get data like [1:2,3:2] from somewhere else, so you have to deal with it? Otherwise I'd recommend [1-2,3-2] instead, because there are libraries assuming that representation.

Comment: Maybe you want to write something like: `sort(split(L),Processed)`? That is not possible in Prolog: There are no functions - only relations.

Comment: @false yes, sort(split(L),Processed) would have been awesome. As you can tell, I am a total newbie in Prolog. (hopefully) I won't have to deal with it anymore after this semester ;)

Comment: You'r welcome! Maybe you will learn to like it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd really like to get rid of the wrapper and just use sort within split

Then use `findall` with a complex goal such as

```
split(Edges, NodeSet) :-
    findall(Node,
            (member(Edge, Edges), (Edge = (Node:_); Edge = (_:Node))),
            NodeList),
    sort(NodeList, NodeSet).
```

However, once you start using aggregating predicates, you could just as well skip the `sort` and use `setof`:

```
split(Edges, NodeSet) :-
    setof(Node, Edge^Pair^(member(Edge, Edges),
                           Edge =.. [:|Pair],
                           member(Node,Pair)),
          NodeSet).
```

Read as: get the set of all `Node` s.t. there exists `Edge` and there exists `Pair` s.t. (etc.) and call that `NodeSet`.

The `=..` ("univ") operator deconstructs a pair: `Edge =.. [:, Left, Right]`. For better readability, you can write a separate predicate to get nodes from edges:

```
% endpoint(Edge, Node) is true iff Node is an endpoint of Edge
endpoint(Node:_, Node).
endpoint(_:Node, Node).

split(Edges, NodeSet) :-
    setof(Node, Edge^(member(Edge, Edges), endpoint(Edge, Node)), NodeSet).
```

**EDIT** Before you try this approach, see the discussion below this answer for whether or not this is a better idea than the OP's original code.

Comment: What do you gain here, compared to the original `split/2`? Except that your solution does not work should variables be present.

Comment: @false: you can't find a set of elements from a list containing variables anyway. What you gain is that you now have a goal, or pair of goals, that you can plug into the middle of a larger clause without having to name them because the recursion is now implicit. That's the reason that these predicates exist.

Comment: (=..)/2 ?!?! Is this the 1970s? :-)

Comment: @false: what do you suggest in its place?

Comment: Using directly variables does not make sense, but they might occur as an extra argument. Are you sure this will never happen? I would not be that sure.

Comment: "what do you suggest in its place?" I think the `split/2` is ok. It is very robust. Even to "odd" things. For `setof/3` that gets a big term like `Edges`, so many things can happen - like unexpected unifications and the like. Maybe not here. But I have seen this so often.

Comment: @false: it's true that this version of the predicate accepts lists with garbage in them, I'll give you that. But it fits the higher-order style that I've grown fond of ever since I went from logic programming to functional programming, and that I personally find easier to read now.

Comment: I do understand the elegance argument, but it is extremely brittle since the quantification is so implicit. Should there be some failure in between the goal will still succeed! Contrast this to the clean monotonic higher-order predicates like `maplist/2..` If there something is failing, the entire goal fails. Also, `maplist/2..` and its kin collaborates perfectly with constraints. But setof/3 is not prepared for it ; nor will it ever be (most probably).

Comment: @larsman: Sorry, I missed your univ-question. (I still do not understand life-update, seens that sometimes I miss something, and sometimes it is perfect). So what is bad? It admits a much larger set than intended (here, in this case). Think of it: you have as nodes a list of other nodes. And now you confuse one level of lists - and promptly your `(=..)/2` would now give you 1 and [2,3]... In other words: Not enough typing (not that I am longing for a type system ...)

Comment: @false: a good H-O type system is one of the additions to Prolog that I'd love (Mercury is quite interesting in this regard). I already strengthened the code by making it `Edge =.. [:|Pair]`; a `length(Pair,2)` check could strengthen it further.

Comment: The biggest problem is how such a system interacts with "the rest of Prolog". Tom Schrijvers had a type system that permits some dynamic conversions. I did comment a lot on this in 2008. But it did not yet develop. Also, there is no `list` type. Only a `list_of/1` type. See what I mean?

Comment: @false: I'm going to end this discussion unilaterally if you don't mind -- I'm not as steeped in Prolog theory as you are. My post answers the OP's question, but I added a note to it pointing to this discussion, so your concerns can be read. If you post them as a separate answer and leave a comment here, I'd certainly consider upvoting it.

Comment: `setof` (and `bagof` as well) seems to preserve variables in the list, so it seems to be the proper solution here. +1 = 400! :)